# Why do we use Optional[ListNode]?

Tags: python, linked-list

I'm new to python programming. While solving a question on leetcode, I came across the below line of code.

```
def deleteDuplicates(self, head: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
```

It'd be very helpful if someone can explain why do we use `Optional[ListNode]`?

**What does it do? How is it useful? **

Comment: because an empty list is represented by `None`, which isn't a `ListNode`. `Optional[Type]` means `Type|NoneType`

Answer (score 2):

It is to allow for values that can be None.

For example: These are all listnodes: (3 -> 1 -> None)

Example:

```
# Use Optional[] for values that could be None
x: Optional[str] = some_function()
```

Source:
https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cheat_sheet_py3.html#

Answer (score 0):

Optional type is used to enable "None" values.

"Optional[X] is equivalent to X | None (or Union[X, None])."

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html